# I'm new in Salesforce and have question regarding SOQL Query in salesforce

Tags: salesforce, apex, soql

Write a SOQL query to fetch Contacts from Account using record Id.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I am confuse because I know this query [select id, name,(select id,AccountId from Contacts) from Account where...] but what should I need to use in WHERE clause?. This is my question. Hope you understood.

Comment: Have you read the [documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_select.htm)?

Answer (score 0):

You can fetch contact information from account by using the following query:

```
SELECT Id, Name, (SELECT AccountId, Name, Email  FROM Contacts) 
FROM Account WHERE Id = 'record Id'
```